# rxJava debounce() operator not working with Observable.range()

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

AFAIK, the `debounce()` operator of rxJava is used for delaying emission of events. When I apply it with the search box it work normally:

```
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(editText)
                .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) //Only emit after 1 sec
                .subscribe(new Observer<TextViewTextChangeEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(TextViewTextChangeEvent event) {
                        //Get more information about text change event
                        Log.e(TAG, "Before: " + event.before() + ", start: " + event.start() + ", count: " + event.count());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.e(TAG, "textChangeEvents: onComplete");
                    }
                });
```

But when I apply it with `Observable.range()` like this:

```
Observable.range(1, 10000)
                .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(@NonNull Long integer) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

the emission keep coming to `onNext()` very fast (about 1000 emissions/s) and continuously although I have applied `debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILISECONDS)` operator.

**Want I am expecting is**: when I'm using `debounce()` only 1 number will be emitted after a delay of 1000 miliseconds (it can skip numbers when delaying between 2 emissions). Means emission will go downstream one by one like the search box example above.

I'm new to rx please help me to achieve this and explain why? I don't really know why I MUST use another operator but `debounce()` because the idea is the same!

Comment: `debounce` prevents the downstream from getting overwhelmed by defining a grace period which must elapse between events in order to get the last event. Range will go through its items as fast it can. The extensions project for 2.x has the [`spanout`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersspanout) operator for this.

Comment: @akarnokd I did not get it, why they cannot be applied the same way but using spanout?

Comment: Different operators are for different purposes, transformations and coordination patterns.

Comment: @akarnokd, sir, with my understanding only the last value (10000) should be emitted, because those items are emitted "as fast as it is possible", thus each time 1000ms counter is being reset, and only when last item (10000) is emitted then 1000ms would finally lapse. Isn't this how should `debounce()` function?

Comment: @azizbekian It will only emit the last value (10000) when I observe it on Android main thread (cause app to not responding)

Comment: @nhoxbypass, then it works as expected. What is your requirement?

Comment: @azizbekian but when I observe in worker thread, It's not working as I expected. It keep emiting items.

Comment: How do you observe on a worker thread? With your current implementation (posted in the question), is the `onNext()` called multiple times?

Comment: I see your updated requirement. Then akarnokd already gave the answer: use `spanout` operator. Why won't it fit your needs?

Comment: @azizbekian I use `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` (but the result is also the same without observeOn()). `onNext` called multiple times. Sorry I'm new and I don't really know why I must use another operator but `debounce`!!!

Comment: This works for me and prints 10000 only: `Observable.range(1, 10000)        .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)        .blockingSubscribe(System.out::println);`. Are you sure you chained `debounce` properly in your flow?

Comment: @akarnokd please read my question again, I've updated. So I must use `spanout` to achieve my expectation? Why emission do not go downstream one by one like the search box example above?

Comment: Yes, use `spanout`. Debounce is by design will emit the latest element after some quiet time. You have to understand that each operator has its own emission pattern to support various use cases and you can't just use them for other purposes.

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you very very much!!!! please summarize your explain and post as answer as clearly as possible. If after 6 days no clearer answer I can give the bounty and marked accepted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`debounce` prevents the downstream from getting overwhelmed by defining a grace period which must elapse between events in order to get the last event, in other words, it will emit the latest element after some quiet time. Range will go through its items as fast it can thus there won't be enough time between items and only the very last will be emitted.

`debounce` is simply not the operator your use case requires. The extensions project for 2.x has the [spanout](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersspanout) operator for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is *per item '.delay()'* operator. See description here -
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#delay-rx.functions.Func1-

```swift
Observable
    .range(1, 10000)
    .delay(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Long>>() {
        @Override
            public Observable<Long> call(Integer integer) {
                return Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
            }
    });
```

For the good order, *'.debounce()'* is absolutely out of question for this use case.

Comment: But, why I cannot use `debounce`? What is the difference between 2 usecase?

Comment: because debounce prevents events from coming too often by skipping them, not by delaying

Comment: I know debounce skipping items. But when I increase the number of item to emit, like `range(1, 1000000000)` then I use `debounce` with 500 milisecs. I think 1000000000 will emit in a longer time than 500 milisecs, but it still only emit the last item.

Comment: only time interval between events matters. apparently in your case they manage to have a bigger interval between them. does it behave the same if you add another scheduler as the 3rd parameter of debounce?

Answer (score 1):

use delay instead of debounce

```
Observable.range(1, 10000)
          .delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
          .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: But, why I cannot use `debounce`? What is the difference?

Comment: @nhoxbypass debounce drops values if they are emitted too often, in your case all values are emitted almost in the same time, so debounce will drop all values except 1

Comment: delay will make a pause after each value

Comment: emitting of `range(1, 1000000000)` is really fast operation, less than 500ms

Answer (score 1):

```
  Observable.range(1, 10000)
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            // Run on a background thread
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            // Be notified on the main thread
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(....);
```

Try this way.